# Why std::queue creation with std::vector container does not raise compiler error

Tags: c++, stl, queue, stdvector

Why `std::queue` creation with `std::vector` container does not raise compiler error?

Compiler error occurs only when pop is called (this is clear as vector does not provide `pop_front()`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    queue<int, vector<int>> s;

    s.push(10);

    cout << s.front() << endl;

    s.pop();

    return 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1740e70f9f5b2fd5)

Comment: What is a "non-default std::vector"?

Comment: @KerrekSB: meant as std::vector is not the default container for queue (which is std::deque). edited the title anyway. yes much clearer.

Comment: Well, creation works. It is `pop` that doesn't work, so you get the error there.

Comment: Good call. This seems to be a quality of implementation issue. Definitely desirable. Whether it’s strictly *necessary* is a question I can’t answer, although to my eyes the standard suggests that it might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the member function of a class template will not be implicit instantiated until it being called.

From $14.7.1/2 Implicit instantiation [temp.inst]:

> Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been
>   explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization
>   of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is
>   referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist;

And /4:

```
[ Example:
template<class T> struct Z {
void f();
void g();
};
void h() {
Z<int> a; // instantiation of class Z<int> required
Z<char>* p; // instantiation of class Z<char> not required
Z<double>* q; // instantiation of class Z<double> not required
a.f(); // instantiation of Z<int>::f() required
p->g(); // instantiation of class Z<char> required, and
// instantiation of Z<char>::g() required
}
```

And /11:

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function
>   template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member
>   function, a member class, or a static data member of a class template
>   that does not require instantiation.

Comment: I don’t think this explains why no diagnostic is required, and if I read §23.6.3.1/1 correctly, this seems to imply that a diagnostic *is* in fact required: “ Any sequence container supporting operations … can be used to instantiate `queue`” — doesn’t this imply that no other container can be used to instantiate `queue`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, the container has to satisfy those requirements, so no other *standard* container can be used (you could make your own, though). This is one of the things that Concepts will do in C++17 (finally).

Comment: @KonradRudolph If you don't call `pop()`, it will not be instantiated, so no one try to call a nonexistent `pop_front()` on `vector`. So it depends on your usage on it.

Comment: @songyuanyao I don’t think that this is relevant here. The *class* has to check that the requirements are met (e.g. via `static_assert`) when the class is instantiated, not the compiler (which isn’t allowed to, due to the paragraphs you cited). I think this answer is wrong. At the very least, the class is definitely *allowed* to diagnose this at the time of instantiation, whereas your answer implicitly suggests that this isn’t the case.

Comment: @konradrudolph: but the standard does not require every potentially undefined behaviour to be flagged with a diagnostic.

Comment: @rici I don’t think this is undefined behaviour. It’s clearly defined which operations need to be supported by the `Container` argument of the `std::queue` class template.

Comment: @KonradRudolph But the technology requirment here, is "if you use pop(), please provide pop_front. If not, then no need." Let's think about `vector`, you can initialize it like `vector<X> v(10)`, but it needs X must have a default ctor. But if you appoint a default value to it, it could be used for those class without a default ctor, such as `vector<X> v(10, X(99))`. So this is the requirement of `vector`.

Comment: @songyuanyao No, that’s definitely wrong, that is *not* the requirement, and nothing in the standard implies that. On the contrary, the standard explicitly says that a type needs *all* these operations to be used with `std::queue`. Again, that’s §23.6.3.1/1. The only question is whether this requires a diagnostic. Your `std::vector` example is a very different case because `std::vector` has no requirement on `T` to be default constructible; only the relevant constructor does.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: If it is not undefined, then what is it? The sentence you cite does not say "*Only* sequence containers...". It doesn't add, "and other ones cannot". It simply specifies that sequence containers which do support those operations can be used. So it's certainly not ill-formed; it can only be unspecified or undefined. Moreover, the standard library implementation is only required to be *consistent* with the specification; it is (explicitly) allowed to additionally implement other features (or produce predictable results in situations not required to do so by the standard).

Comment: @KonradRudolph "a type needs all these operations to be used with std::queue", but does all of the operations of `queue` are needed? The problem is until user calls `pop`, it will not be generated, and then `pop_front` will not be called, so no compile errors. Of course I agree with it doesn't make sense not to call `pop` on `queue`..

Comment: @songyuanyao “but does all of the operations of `queue` are needed” — yes, explicitly, as the quoted passage shows. Your `std::vector` example is very different because `std::vector` doesn’t require `DefaultConstructible` item types (23.2), only the relevant constructor does: §23.3.6.2/4 “`explicit vector(size_type n);` … Requires: `T` shall be `DefaultConstructible`.”

Comment: @KonradRudolph But, §23.6.3.1/1 does ask for the implemention of `queue` to do some special check beyond the basic facilities what the language provides. Isn't it unpratical?

Comment: @songyuanyao “Isn’t it unpractical?” No, not at all. Before C++11 it was certainly a bit convoluted but other libraries have been doing such checks for quite some time. C++11 made this much easier (and in the future it will be easier still). However, rici’s last comment adds good points which convinced me (tentatively) that this may not be mandatory after all.